# Regression points and regression table on bayesian model

Tags: r, bayesian, regression-coefficients

I used `bas.lm()` function to build a bayesian model in R, but when it comes to run the `get_regression_table(model)` and `get_regression_points(model)`, it says "Only simple and multiple linear regression models are supported. Try again using `lm` for your models as appropriate". I have a linear model in the form of $y=a+b_i X_i$, my variables are counted in rates (values from 0 to 1). 
What should i do?
my code is:

```
model <- bas.lm(V128 ~ . , data = subset, method="MCMC", prior = "ZS-null", modelprior = uniform())
```

my data are: 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFTRV.png

Comment: Can you include the R code you used to build your model in your question? It's hard to answer your question without seeing the actual R code.

Comment: I put my coding as well

Comment: Thanks, Eva!  Can you also add some information on your "subset" data? For example, use the command *head(subset, 2)* and show the first two rows of your data. (You can manually alter some of the actual data values when you add the output to your post in order to preserve the confidentiality of your data - if the actual value is 2.5, say, just change it to something else that is "close enough".)  Also, show the output of the command *str(subset)* (possibly with manually altered data values) to enable us to understand what predictor variables you have in your data and how R treats them.

Comment: Thank you for the instruction. I have uploaded my data information.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the get_regression_table() function from the *moderndive* package to extract the summary of the model object produced by the bas.lm() function. However, the get_regression_table() function expects your model object to be obtained with the lm() function not with the bas.lm() function.  This is the reason you are seeing the error.

Commands that would work for your bas.lm() model object include:

*summary(model)*: used to print a summary of the results;

*plot(model)*: used to plot posterior distributions for the model coefficients;

*coefficients(model)*: used to extract the posterior summaries of model coefficients.

See R's help documentation for more details: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BAS/versions/0.3/topics/bas.lm.

The same explanation applies to the function get_regression_points() from the *moderndive* package - the function only accepts lm() model objects, but your model object is a bas.lm() model object, which is not recognized by get_regression_points(). You can see this from the help file for get_regression_points(), which states: "Currently only lm is supported.".

Comment: So i can get the information from the regressions table and regression points by the summary(model), plot(model) etc?

Comment: The moderndive package was NOT written for use with bam.ls objects, so there is no reason to expect that you would get identical information from commands that were written for bam.ls objects, like summary(). You just need to play with the commands I suggested and see what you get.

Comment: okay, thank you very much!!!!

Comment: You're welcome, Eva! 